# Number Theory : $\frac{x + y }{\gcd(x,y)} \geq q$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

How would you go about the following proof?

Let $q > 1$ be an odd positive integer. Show that $q$ is prime if and only if for any set of $\frac{(q+1)}{2}$ distinct positive integers, there exist two integers $x$ and $y$ in the set such that $\frac{(x+y)}{\gcd(x, y)} ≥ q$.

I tried looking at a base case of $q=3$ at first, and then used induction but I'm not sure what to induct upon. Like I can create more primes in the form $pq+1$, but I'm just not sure what to do beyond that point.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  An obvious starting point would be to analyze the situation for specific $q$, such as $q=3$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. How would _you_ go about this? If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help. Just asking us to do it for you is not appropriate here.

Comment: In all fairness to the OP, this was [in my opinion anyway!] quite a challenging exercise. @sam where is this from? In any event the "if" direction is also just established too.

Comment: Btw an Olympiad Problem, I forget which one!!!

Answer (score 2):

This problem is harder and more interesting than it has gotten credit for. **EDIT: We first establish "only if" direction. And then below, we establish the "if" direction**:

**The "only if" direction. Here we establish THM 1 stated next.**

**THM 1.** *Let $q$ be a prime integer and let $X$ be a
set of $\frac{q+1}{2}$ positive integers. Then there is at least one pair $x,y
\in X$ such that $\frac{x+y}{\gcd(x,y)} \ge q$.*

Proof: Suppose this is not true. Then the following must hold:

**Lemma 2.** *Let $x,y \in X$ with $x \pmod q = -(y \pmod q) \not =
0$. Then the inequality $\frac{x+y}{\gcd(x,y)} \ge q$ holds.*

*Proof of Lemma 2:* Note that $\gcd(x,y)$ must divide $x+y$. However,
$x+y=aq$ for some positive integer $a$, and as $q$ is prime and
neither $x,y$ is divisible by $q$, it follows that $\gcd(x+y)$ must
divide $a$ and thus the inequality $\gcd(x+y) \le a $ holds. The
result follows from noting this inequality $\gcd(x+y) \le a$, together
with $x+y=aq$. $\surd$

**Lemma 3.** *Suppose there exists an $x,y \in X$ with $x \pmod q = y
\pmod q \not = 0$.  Then the inequality
$\frac{x+y}{\gcd(x,y)} \ge q$ holds.*

*Proof of Lemma 3:* Let us write $x' = \frac{x}{\gcd(x,y)}$ and $y' =
\frac{y}{\gcd(x,y)}$. Then the equation $\frac{x+y}{\gcd(x,y)}=x'+y'$
holds. So to prove Lemma 3, it suffices to show that $x'+y'$ is at
least $q$. However, $x'$ and $y'$ are distinct positive integers with
$x' \pmod q = y' \pmod q' \not = 0$, so at least one of $x',y'$ must
be at least $q$. As both $x',y'$ are positive, it follows that $x'+y'$
is indeed greater than $q$, which as observed earlier, suffices to
show Lemma 3.  $\surd$

**Lemma 4.** *Let $x,y \in X$ such that exactly one of $x,y$ is a
multiple of $q$. Then the inequality $\frac{x+y}{\gcd(x,y)} \ge q$
holds.*

*Proof of Lemma 4:* Let $x$ be the multiple of $q$. Write $x=bq$ for
some integer $b$; as $x$ is positive it follows that $b$ must be
positive as well. As $q$ is prime and does not divide $y$ it follows
that $\gcd(x,y)$ must divide $b$. Thus the inequality $\gcd(x,y) \le
b$ must hold. However, the inequality $x+y \ge x = bq$ must also hold,
and so from this Lemma 4 follows. $\surd$

*REMAINDER OF THE PROOF OF THM 1:* First, let us assume WLOG that
there is no integer $a$ that divides every element in $X$. Then $q$
does not divide every integer in $X$. By Lemma 4 then, every element
$x \in X$ must satisfy $x \pmod q \in \{1,2,\ldots, q-1\}$, lest there
is a pair $x,y \in X$ such that the inequality $\frac{x+y}{\gcd(x+y)}
\ge q$ holds. By Lemma 3 then, at least one of the following holds:

- There is a pair $x,y \in X$ such that the inequality
  $\frac{x+y}{\gcd(x+y)} \ge q$ holds, or
- The set $X$ must also satisfy the following condition (X):
  If $x,y$ are in $X$, then $x \pmod q \not = y \pmod q \not = 0$.

However, if $X$ satisfies (X), then as $|X| \ge \frac{q+1}{2}$, it
follows that there is a pair $x,y \in X$ such that $x \pmod q=-(y
\pmod q) \not = 0$. From this however, Lemma 2 implies that there is a
pair $x,y \in X$ such that the inequality $\frac{x+y}{\gcd(x+y)} \ge
q$ holds after all; namely, any pair $x,y \in X$ such that $x \pmod q=-(y \pmod q) \not = 0$ will do. And so THM 1 follows. $\checkmark$

**The "if" direction. Here let $q$ be an odd integer that is not prime. We explicitly construct a set $X$ of $\frac{q+1}{2}$ positive integers such that for all $x,y\in X$ the strict inequality $\frac{x+y}{\gcd(x,y)}<q$ holds.**
First, let $p$ be a prime that divides $q$; as $q$ is odd and not prime it follows that $p \ge 3$ and $q=pr$ for some $r \ge 3$. Then consider
$$X= A + B,$$
where
$$A=\{1,2,3,\ldots,(p-1),p\},$$ and
$$B=\Big\{(p+1) + 2i;$$
$$i=0,1,\ldots ,$$ $$\Big(\frac{q+1}{2}-(p+1)\Big)\Big\}.$$

Then one can check the following:

1. For each $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ the inequality $x+y \le q$ holds, with $x+y = q$ only if both $x$ is the largest element in $A$ and $y$ the largest in $B$.
2. Letting $x$ be the largest element in $A$ and $y$ the largest in $B$, note that $p$ divides both $x$ and $y$.
3. The integer $2$ divides each element in $B$, and the sum of every two elements in $B$ is strictly less than $2q$.
4. Finally, the sum of every two elements in $A$ is strictly less than $q$.

Then from 1--4 conclude that $X$ is indeed as claimed.

To tie this back to the "only if" proof, there is a pair $x,y$ such that $x+y$ is a multiple of $q$ [namely $x$ is the largest element in $A$ and $y$ the largest element in $B$, and $x+y=cq$ where here $c=1$, and there is a prime dividing both $x$ and $y$. Compare w Lemma 2 above.